# Why is an initialized dictionary argument in a function in Python 3 immutable?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

In the following defined function,

```
def a_function(x, dictionary = dict()):
    if not dictionary:
        print('Empty Dictionary')
        dictionary['A'] = 1
        dictionary['B'] = 2
    return dictionary.get(x)
```

it takes in `'A'` or `'B'` and returns `1` or `2`. The dictionary argument is supposed to be initialized each time, but when I run it, it is immutable, in that once created, it doesn't start again. `'Empty Dictionary'` is run only once. Why?

```
>> a_function('A')
Empty Dictionary
1
>> a_function('B')
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) states that:

> Default parameter values are evaluated from left to right when the
> function definition is executed.
>
> This means that **the expression is
> evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same
> “pre-computed” value is used for each call**.

For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def f(foo=datetime.datetime.now()):
...     print(foo)

>>> f()
2020-01-21 05:21:35.084471
>>> f()
2020-01-21 05:21:35.084471
```